# Missing whole disk device in OpenSolaris

Tags: solaris, opensolaris, zfs

I have begun experimenting with Solaris and ZFS as a NAS.  All was going very smoothly until I had a drive failure.  When I replaced the drive, I no longer have a device file mapped to the whole disk. `/dev/dsk/c7t3d0` does not exist but `c7t2d0` and `c7t4d0` both do.  Also the `sd@3,0:wd` file under the `/devices/` tree is non-existent.  Do I have to prepare/partition the disk somehow to cause the whole disk device to exist?

Here are a few outputs that might be useful.

```
jeffmc@ats-ds2:/dev/dsk$ zpool status
  pool: datapool
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices could not be opened.  Sufficient replicas exist for
        the pool to continue functioning in a degraded state.
action: Attach the missing device and online it using 'zpool online'.
   see: http://www.sun.com/msg/ZFS-8000-2Q
 scrub: none requested
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        datapool    DEGRADED     0     0     0
          mirror-0  DEGRADED     0     0     0
            c7t2d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c7t3d0  UNAVAIL      0     0     0  cannot open
          mirror-1  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c7t4d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c7t5d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

```
jeffmc@ats-ds2:/dev/dsk$ zpool replace datapool c7t3d0
cannot open 'c7t3d0': no such device in /dev/dsk
must be a full path or shorthand device name
```

```
jeffmc@ats-ds2:/dev/dsk$ sudo format
Searching for disks...done


AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:
       0. c7t0d0 
          /pci@0,0/pci8086,3599@6/pci8086,330@0/pci1014,2cc@7,1/sd@0,0
       1. c7t1d0 
          /pci@0,0/pci8086,3599@6/pci8086,330@0/pci1014,2cc@7,1/sd@1,0
       2. c7t2d0 
          /pci@0,0/pci8086,3599@6/pci8086,330@0/pci1014,2cc@7,1/sd@2,0
       3. c7t3d0 
          /pci@0,0/pci8086,3599@6/pci8086,330@0/pci1014,2cc@7,1/sd@3,0
       4. c7t4d0 
          /pci@0,0/pci8086,3599@6/pci8086,330@0/pci1014,2cc@7,1/sd@4,0
       5. c7t5d0 
          /pci@0,0/pci8086,3599@6/pci8086,330@0/pci1014,2cc@7,1/sd@5,0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
devfsadm -v
```

otherwise, it might be an EFI partition is required. It should be created with:

```
format -e
```

or

```
fdisk -E raw-device
```

Comment: Good call on EFI. The disk had a dos partition table with one big Solaris partition. I rebuild as EFI and all was well.